# Workaround for GET XMLHttpRequest (local request) size limits

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, xmlhttprequest

### Problem

Whilst developing a chrome extension I encountered a problem where I try to retrieve large JSON file (~1GB) using `XMLHttpRequest` GET request. The file is located on my local machine and I retrieve the download link using `chrome.runtime.getURL('data.json')` from a content script.

The error I am getting is

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at xhr.onreadystatechange (<anonymous>:11:23)
    at XMLHttpRequest.<anonymous>
```

I assumed it is because the JSON file is too large and therefore, it is not possible to download it in one go (please correct me if this wouldn't be the case). Is there any workaround for this size limitation?

### Additional info

I generate the JSON file from a python script, thus, it is completely possible to choose a different format (some binary format maybe) if necessary.

Furthermore, I cannot use any API provided for chrome extensions since the script I am actually calling the `XMLHttpRequest` from is not a content script but an appended script to the body of the website.

Here is a minimal code for reproduction (don't forget to configure the `content_security_policy` in the manifest to enable inline script execution).

```js
// Content script

function init() {

    let script = document.createElement("script");
    script.appendChild(document.createTextNode(__magic.toString() + "; __magic('" + chrome.runtime.getURL('data.json') + "');"));
    script.id = "__magic";
    document.body.appendChild(script);
}

function __magic(url) {
    var db;
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.onreadystatechange = () => { 
        if (xhr.readyState === 4) {
            db = JSON.parse(xhr.response);
            window.setInterval(check, 10);
        }
    };
    xhr.open("GET", url, true);
    xhr.send();
}

init();
```

Edit

---

I forgot to say that I was successful in loading the big JSON file in python, thus, I think it is safe to assume that the JSON file is not corrupted.

Furthermore, the JSON file is storing a graph structure - I choose following layout for the json file

```
{
 "node1": {
   "children": ["node2", "node3"],
   "foo": 15
 },
 "node2": {
   "children": ["node15", "node1"],
   "foo": 90
 },
 ...
}
```

I bet there is a more efficient way of storing a graph structure rather than using JSON, however, so far I could not find any that would be compatible with javascript.

Comment: try with xhr.responseType = "json" and no parse the response.
1Gb is a very big file.
Try to validate the json file with some tool, maybe it is corrupted

Comment: I was able to load the JSON file in python, thus, I think the JSON file is okay

Answer (score 0):

1. save the response in a new file and confront the size with the original file.
2. try with xhr.responseType = "json" and no parse the response (if you can)
3. try to split the local file into smaller chunks and make several asyncromous xmlhttprequest\fetch requests (Promise.all) and then joint the responses into your big final json file.

Comment: Do you know what are the limits of one chunk/request?